# Get color bar for scatter plot in matplotlib with discrete ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to to get a scatter plot with color bar having discrete ticks that bound each of the colors used. Presently, the following code merges top two colors.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

a1 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, 10)
a2 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, 10)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))

limits1 = [min(a2), max(a2)]
bounds1 = np.linspace(limits1[0], limits1[1], 5)
colors1 = plt.get_cmap('jet')(np.linspace(0, 1, len(bounds1)))
cmap1 = mcolors.ListedColormap(colors1[1:-1])
norm1 = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds1, ncolors=len(bounds1)-1)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
im1 = ax1.scatter(a1, a2, c=a2, norm=norm1, cmap=cmap1)
fig.colorbar(im1, orientation='vertical', shrink=1, aspect=30, pad=0.03, extend='neither', ticks=bounds1, label='ampWT')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when running this line:

```
cmap1 = mcolors.ListedColormap(colors1[1:-1])
```

You're effectively removing the first and last colors from the colors1 list.
Since you started with 5 colors (bounds1 is length 5) you're left with 3 colors, which explains why you don't have the correct number of colors.

If you want to fix it you have 2 solutions:

1. just add another color in the beginning to have 6 initial colors and remove 2

```
bounds1 = np.linspace(limits1[0], limits1[1], 5)
colors1 = plt.get_cmap('jet')(np.linspace(0, 1, len(bounds1)+1)) # add 1 color 
cmap1 = mcolors.ListedColormap(colors1[1:-1])
norm1 = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds1, ncolors=len(bounds1))
```

2. choose the final number of colors from the beginning (4)

```
bounds1 = np.linspace(limits1[0], limits1[1], 5)
colors1 = plt.get_cmap('jet')(np.linspace(0, 1, len(bounds1)-1)) # changed length of colors
cmap1 = mcolors.ListedColormap(colors1) # changed colors input
norm1 = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds1, ncolors=len(colors1)) # changed ncolors
```

The final colors are not the same, so pick the one you prefer